# How to get the full path to a file on iOS 8?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

I'm using an iPod Touch 5G with iOS 8 and I would like to get the full path to a file, e.g. an image in the Camera Roll. I couldn't find a native option to do that - do I need to download an app for that?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you clarify exactly *why* you want what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the 'full path' to a file on a non-jailbroken device is not useful as you can't access the file directly anyway. Generally, this is not possible, although you may be able to infer the location of a specific file.

For what it's worth, the full path to an image in your camera roll is:

```
/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/###APPLE/IMG_####.png
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does the "#" in "###APPLE" stand for?

Comment: @Sven This is an incremental number representing the number of thousands that the IMG integer is currently at (starting at 100APPLE). For example, all the IMG_2###.png are in a folder called 102APPLE, and all IMG_3###.png are in a folder called 103APPLE. This allows for over 9999 images.